# Process ID and OS Information in C++

Tags: c++

In python I can use os.getpid() and os.name() to get information about the Process ID and
OS name. Is there something similar in C++? I tried GetProcessId() but was told that this is undeclared... I am using Cygwin under windows.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Standard C++ has no such functionality. You need to use OS specific features to get this. In your case, you need to look up POSIX/UNIX functions such as [getpid()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getpid.html).

Note that if you actually do want to call the Windows functions to get process ID etc, you should be using a C++ environment like [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), which allows you to build native Windows applications, rather than Cygwin, which is more aimed at porting POSIX apps to Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your information gents. And how can I get information about the Operating System, is there also some function?

Answer (score 1):

To use [GetProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683215(VS.85).aspx) you need to include Windows.h and link to Kernel32.lib. See [Process and Thread Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684847(VS.85).aspx) for more information.

I use [MSYS/mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) instead of [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). So, you may need the [w32api](http://cygwin.com/packages/w32api/) package installed.

Comment: cygwin is basically a posix environment, not a windows one

Comment: I use MSYS and link to Win32 libs. Can you not do so with cygwin?

Comment: MSYS and cygwin are completely different animals

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Hart's book "Win32 System Programming".  Great discussion about how to manage processes, memory, files etc in Kernel32, if you're just starting to look at Windows programming.  You can also get a free version of Visual Studio (http://www.microsoft.com/express/).